# Z3's Java interpolation API seems to return wrong interpolants

Tags: java, api, z3

I'm trying to create some simple examples that use the Z3's Java interpolation API. My intent is to replicate the following SMT-LIB:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(compute-interpolant (> x 5) (< x 5))
```

When I give the above SMT-LIB to Z3 on stdin it returns:

```
unsat
(not (<= x 5))
```

which is a valid interpolant.

However, when I try to solve the same problem via the Java API:

```
    System.out.print("Z3 Major Version: ");
    System.out.println(Version.getMajor());
    System.out.print("Z3 Full Version: ");
    System.out.println(Version.getString());
    HashMap<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<String, String>();
    cfg.put("proof", "true");
    cfg.put("model", "true");
    InterpolationContext ictx = new InterpolationContext(cfg);
    Solver s = ictx.mkSolver();
    // A = x > 5
    // B = x < 5
    //Whats Interp(A,B)?
    IntExpr x = ictx.mkIntConst("x");
    IntExpr five = ictx.mkInt(5);
    BoolExpr A = ictx.mkGt(x, five);
    BoolExpr B = ictx.mkLt(x, five);
    BoolExpr iA = ictx.MkInterpolant(A);
    BoolExpr AB = ictx.mkAnd(A, B);
    BoolExpr pat = ictx.mkAnd(iA, B);
    System.out.println("A: " + A);
    System.out.println("B: " + B);
    System.out.println("Pattern: " +  pat);
    Params params = ictx.mkParams();
    s.add(AB);
    //s.add(B);
    s.check();
    Expr proof = s.getProof();         
    Expr[] interps = ictx.GetInterpolant(proof, pat, params);
    for(int i = 0; i < interps.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Interpolant: " + interps[i]);
    }
```

I get:

```
Z3 Major Version: 4
Z3 Full Version: 4.4.0.0
A: (> x 5)
B: (< x 5)
Pattern: (and (interp (> x 5)) (< x 5))
Interpolant: true
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible fixes:

1) Assert A and B separately, like this:

```
s.add(A)
s.add(B)
```

Asserted formulas that don't appear *verbatim* in the pattern are considered "background theory". In your example, this means that (and (< x 5) (> x 5)) is treated as a tautology and x as part of the interpreted vocabulary, so "true" (or any other formula over x!) is an interpolant.

2) Use the ComputeInterpolant method instead. The only reason to use GetInterpolant is to use the solver incrementally.

Having said the above, I tried (1) and found that the GetInterpolant call was broken. It is now fixed on the unstable branch in github.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I appreciate you taking the time to answer.